# Java: Two Smallest numbers helo

Tags: java

So my code works in all test cases except for when there are only two integers.
Example if user inputs: terminating number as -1 and then inputs 1,2 and then -1 again the smallest numbers are 1,1 and not 1,2

Terminating number is just the way to end the sequence/program.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        double num;
        double min = 0;
        double min2 = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter terminating value:");
        int term = IO.readInt();

        System.out.println("Enter next value:");
        num = IO.readDouble();

        if(num == term){
            IO.reportBadInput();
            main(args);
        }

        int count = 0;
        min = num;
        min2 = num;

        do{
            num = IO.readDouble();

            if(num!= term && num < min) {
                min2 = min;
                min = num;
            }
            else if (num!= term && num < min2) {
                min2 = num;
            }
            count++;
        }while (num != term);

        if(count < 2){
            IO.reportBadInput();
            main(args);
        }

        else{
        IO.outputDoubleAnswer(min);
        IO.outputDoubleAnswer(min2);
        }

    }
```

Comment: why would you disallow the first input to be the terminating value, but the second can be any arbitrary value? you should decide for consistent behaviour. Either prohibit or allow the terminating value for both the first and second input

Comment: What? The terminating value is the number to end the program. The first number has to be a term. number and the second is where the number input starts if its terminating number again the program runs an error and restarts.

Comment: you're code reads the terminating-number and if the **next** value is the terminating-number aswell, you print an error-message. But the second value after entering the terminating-number may be any number, including the terminating-value, which is a rather strange implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your code lies in setting *both* minimal values to the number that was first entered. This is bad because if the user enters the smallest value first, both `min` and `min2` already contain the minimum value. That means the condition `input < min2` is always `false`, causing `min2` to always contain the value the user has entered first.

To fix this, simply set the value of `min2` to a value which is larger than any other value the user could enter (for example `Double.MAX_VALUE` or `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`).

Just as a hint concerning the error-handling part of your code: if you call `main` again after reminding the user that their input was invalid, make sure to add a `return` behind that call or the execution will continue after the called `main` method is finished. Something like this:

```java
if (count < 2) {
    IO.reportBadInput();
    main(args);
    return;
}
```